# Thoughts on Building a Blender-Oriented PC

Tags: rendering, versions

The rendering time on my laptop is starting to become absurd in order to get a decent looking scene. I am looking at building a pc that is well suited for blender. What components are the most important? Most of my projects are rendered using cycles, so a Nvidia graphics card is a must plus lots of ram. But I want some more information, like what cpu (Amd?)? What graphics cards would you recommend? If you have the time could you list a couple different builds such as premium, budget, ect.?

I know that there are other ways of lowering the rendering time (i.e. better poly management), but I have been looking to build my own rig for a while.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about blender.

Comment: I suggest you take this question to Blenderartists.org. There is a forum for technical support in which what you're asking gets asked on a daily basis. Lots of information. The forum nature of that site is better suited for opinion based answers than this site.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't realize my question was off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Note

Although this question is about hardware we need a canonical answer on this!

- [Canonical posts for hardware questions?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354/canonical-posts-for-hardware-questions)
- [Answering vague support questions (once)?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/answering-vague-support-questions-once/184#184)

---

### Answer

Mike Pan has started a thread on BA and collects benchmark results in a [sheet](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480-2-6x-Cycles-render-benchmark).
Be careful because the benchmark results may differ due to different Blender versions and Cycles performance has been optimized.

A few things to consider:

### GPU

Cycles uses [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and is provided by NVIDIA only.
A single system designed for Cycles should be focused on maximum number of shaders kernels (CUDA cores) on the GPU. When you use shaders written in [OSL](https://code.google.com/p/openshadinglanguage/) the scene can only be rendered on the CPU.

Nvidia model numbers start with a digit for the generation 5,6,7

```
 oldest    540 < 550 < 560 < 570 < 580 (fastest, 512 CUDA cores)
           640 < 650 < 660 < 670 < 680 (fastest, 1536 CUDA cores)
 newest    740 < 750 < 760 < 770 < 780 < 780Ti (fastest, 2880 CUDA cores)
```

You could find something like 590, this means AFAIK the two 580's have been connected.

#### GPU RAM

If you use many big textures the RAM of a 1.5GiB card could be the limiting factor more is better.

#### CPU

Baking, preparation of the scene is calculated only by the CPU. According to the benchmarks I guess Intel is to prefer.

```
i3 2 Cores (slowest)
i5 4 Cores 
i7 4 Cores + Hyper-threading (fastest) Hyper-Threating adds approx. 10-20% of performance.
```

#### Server CPU

A Xeon-CPUs an E3-1231-v3 (4-cores) costs a bit more than an i5 but comes with Hyper-threading. . There also costly CPUs like E5 available Depending on the motherboard you can add 2 of them (Socket 2011) having hexa(6), octa(8) or deca(10) cores (plus hypertheading which adds ~10% performance) but they cost > 1.250$ (Sep. 2014).

### System RAM

- Should start at 8GiB, 16GiB would be suitable for most use cases.

### Realated Resources

- [Blender Cycles performance benchmark - more CPU cores vs higher clock frequency benchmark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-6sr6vM6II)
- [Cycles versions speed comparision](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/proof-that-cycles-is-getting-faster-speed-comparisons/)

Some numbers from my machines for Mike Pan's BMW:

Blender v2.71

```
i5-3470@3.2 GHz 02:50.00
CUDA GeForce GTX 660 Ti 01:12.65

Xeon E3-1231@3.4 GHz 01:36.48
CUDA GeForce GTX 580 01:08.23

i7-2630QM@2.0 GHz 03:39.96
CUDA GeForce GTX 560M 03.00.87
```

You find a lot more results at:

- [Blenchmark benchmarks-overview](http://mad-creations.nl/blenchmark/benchmarks-overview)